# setting nav active based on position of y

Tags: jquery, css

So instead of describing what I am trying to accomplish, here is an [example](http://www.pareup.com/#pareup) On the right side of the screen they have a nav and based on what slide you are on will change the 'active' nav item.

So I have this figured out if I use the position() function and subclass .top. (as you will see in my code, it works fine if I say < position.top) except it absolutely just won't let me use any conditional statement that lets me compare AGAINST position.top (as you will see in my code my second conditional statement doesn't run when I try to do var > position.top).

Was hoping someone can lend me some advice on how I can do this, if it's this way or something else.

```
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($this.hasClass("green"))
    {
          if ($window.scrollTop() < pos) {
        $this.css({
            background: 'green'
        });
        } else {
        $this.css({

            background: 'black'
        });
        }
    }


    });
};
var a = $(".slide1n");
var Aposition = a.position();

if(Aposition.top < 875)
{
  //this runs
  $('.slide1n').addClass('green');
  $('.slide1n').followTo(875);
}

if(Aposition.top > 875)
{
  //this doesnt run
  $('.slide1n').removeClass('green');
  $('.slide2n').addClass('green');
  $('.slide2n').followTo(1550);
}
```

I also tried something else I found, that is STILL not working (before I posted this question, I went back to google and did another search and found a different way, and it's still not working) This just is not making sense to me since if the first two statements (both different times I tried it) work fine if it's less than that amount, and with my followTo function, the div changes from green to black when it's out of bounds, so if it's out of bounds that div's top MUST be above 875 since it turned black. I am out of resources. Thanks in advance.

```
var a = parseInt($(".slide1n").css("top"));

if (a > 0 && a < 875) {
  //this runs
}

if (a > 876) {
  $('body').hide(); //doesnt run this 
}
```

/****** EDITS *********/

HTML (was requested)

```
  <div class="slide1n"></div>
  <div class="slide2n"></div>
  <div class="slide3n"></div>
  <div class="slide4n"></div>
  <div class="slide5n"></div>
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jdmdev.net/scrollnavhelp/index.html)

Comment: can you post your HTML please. or better yet create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: alternatively, if you're ok with using an external library's solution, Bootstrap has a js solution called 'scrollSpy' http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: @haxxxton a) made requested edits above! b) will look into that!! thank you for the reference. I would still like to do it this way, if possible, but thank you again.

Comment: It has to be able to get done because it works fine with the first one (as you'll see in the live demo the first 'circle' is green up until a certain position i determined in the jquery)

Comment: i created a jsfiddle with the code that i use as a go-to for scrollspy style stuff and using your css, html (few minor tweaks), hopefully points you in the right direction: http://jsfiddle.net/DCz6H/

Comment: yes this helps, wow i'm impressed. going to go through this code today, de-engineer it and figure out what's going on. Thank you very much for this, if you want to make that an answer (not sure if it applies to SO's answer rules) but I would glad to give you a check and an up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some liberties with your question and decided to go down my normal go-to JS solution for scrollspy.

```
($(function(){
    // create a cache of used elements
    var $els = [];
    $els.nav = $('#nav');
    $els.header = $('#header');
    $els.window = $(window);
    $els.indicators = $('.indicators');

    var lastId,
    headerHeight = $els.header.outerHeight(),
    // All list items
    menuItems = $els.nav.find('a'),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
        var item = $($(this).attr('href'));
        if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

    // fancy scroll over time to anchor
    function scrollTo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        var topDistance = $(target).offset().top + headerHeight;
        menuItems.parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        // need to trigger this on both as browsers differ from one another
        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: topDistance + 'px'}, 200);
    }

    function checkAnchorUpdate(){
        // Return a list of elements above of at where we are scrolled to
        var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
            if ($(this).offset().top <= $els.window.scrollTop() - headerHeight){
                return this;
            }
        });

        // Get the last element in the returned list
        cur = cur[cur.length-1];
        // get element's id attribute, default to 'slide1'
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "slide1";
        // stops us triggering the active states again and again
        if (lastId !== id) {
            lastId = id;
            // Set/remove active class
            $els.indicators.removeClass('active');
            $('#'+id+'n').addClass('active');
            menuItems
            .parent().removeClass("active")
            .end().filter("[href=\"#"+id+"\"]").parent().addClass("active");

        }  
    }

    $els.window.on('scroll', checkAnchorUpdate);
    menuItems.on('click', scrollTo);
}));
```

There are some caveats and improvements you might want to make such as:

- When you reach the bottom of the page trigger the 'active' state on
  the last item (on larger screens sometimes you wont be able to scroll
  right to the bottom element, but this is just a personal preference).
- Add a throttle/debouncer to the 'scroll' trigger on window (such as
  [Ben Alman's Throttle/Bebounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) jQuery plugin) for performance
  reasons
- Currently you have to have a top menu item for each of the
  'indicators' you want to be visible if you want the indicator to show
  for a particular slide

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DCz6H/2/)

Comment: fixed all these, thanks again man this was incredibly incredibly helpful.